# How to replace lipsum text with online text in LaTeX?

Tags: lipsum, blindtext

The packages `lipsum` and `blindtext` work well enough to flesh-out and format LaTeX documents, but are these packages all that's available? The question to answer in this thread: how can I use newly generated web content in place of the usual text produced by more standard text generators?

Comment: Did you see `kantlipsum`?

Comment: You can downloads whole books and fables from here http://www.gutenberg.org/ in pure text format. Then you can `head` (unix command or similar) or cut as much as you want and `\input` in your document.

Comment: @egreg I like the idea of `kantlipsum` a lot, to use lipsum as a way to learn something new, we all know we read the lipsum text more than we should. It'd be great, later on, if I could link the lipsum to news headlines. As a way to format my documents and keep up with the world, or my Twitter world, all in one go.

Comment: @alfC This sounds like a way to do it. Maybe we could execute unix commands under LaTeX then can makes calls to cURL?

Comment: @Chernoff - of course you can, using `\write18` (realistically `immediate\write18`).  It's probably best to wrap your commands up in a shell script and execute with a single call, and don;t forget to run  `(pdf)latex --shell-escape` to allow calling external code.

Comment: You can use `wget` also, if the website is friendly to it.

Answer (score 3):

In ConTeXt, you can use `\input` and `\externalfigure` to source any `http://` resource as well. So, just pick your favourite online text and simply `\input` it. An example:

```
\starttext

\startasciimode
\input http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/10947/pg10947.txt
\stopasciimode

\stoptext
```

which gives a 208 page document. The `\startasciimode` is to change the catcode of `#` so that it does not cause an error.

Comment: I wish LaTeX had this feature too